# Unpacking dictionary in for loop with indeces

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

I have the following code which iterate over a dictionary to unpack its values:

```
my_dict = {"brand": "A", "product": ["X", "Y", "Z"], "color": ["red", "green", "blue"]}


def my_fnc(product, index):
    print(f"Product {product} at index {index}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    for i, product in enumerate(my_dict["product"], 1):
        my_fnc(product, i)
```

The above code returns the following output:

```
Product X at index 1
Product Y at index 2
Product Z at index 3
```

I'm now trying to retrieve the `color` values across the iteration process. The result I'm looking for is the following:

```
Product X at index 1 is colored red
Product Y at index 2 is colored green
Product Z at index 3 is colored blue
```

and `my_func` should be defined like this:

```
def my_fnc(product, index, color):
    print(f"Product {product} at index {index} is colored {color}")
```

I should note that it's important that I retrieve the index in this way. I tried a couple of things (like iterating through `my_dict.items()`, but I couldn't make it work together with the index.

Comment: `my_dict[‘color’][i - 1]`?

Comment: I might suggest reorganizing your dictionary so that the paired data is actually paired, e.g. `my_dict = {"brand": "A", "product_and_color": [("X", "red"), ("Y", "green"), ("Z", "blue)]}`.  That way you can't ever accidentally mess up your indexing by adding an item to one list but not the other, reordering them, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a for loop that iterates over the range of the length of the product list.

```
for i in range(len(my_dict['product'])):
    my_func(my_dict['product'][i], i+1, my_dict['color'][i])
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `zip()`?

You can try something like:

```
for index, value in enumerate(zip(my_dict["product"], my_dict["color"])):
    my_func(value[0], index, value[1]) # value 1 here would be the color
```

and then change the `my_func` to get color as well.